# Program failing to open file from variable

Tags: c++

I know i'm making a stupid mistake somewhere and even though i've been reading old questions i'm unable to catch it. I'm hoping someone would point me in the right direction. As you can probably tell i'm new to C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  //local variables
  string answer, filePath, wordtest;
  fstream openFile;

  ***stuff removed for space reasons***

  cout << "Enter the full file path" << endl;

  getline(cin, filePath);

  openFile.open(filePath, ios::in);         //Open file

  while (openFile.peek() != EOF)
  {
    cin >> wordtest;
    cout << wordtest;
    //getline(cin, wordtest);
    {
      //wordCount = wordCount + 1;
    }
  }

  openFile.close();
  openFile.clear(std::ios_base::goodbit);

  cout << "Loaded file and read " << wordCount << " words";

}
```

Comment: Some issues: 1) Some revisions of C++ may require `filePath.c_str()` as parameter to `fstream::open()`. 2) Don't use EOF, search StackOverflow for "c++ why eof bad".

Comment: Why are you testing `openFile` for EOF when you use `cin` and `cout` inside the loop?  The `cin` and `cout` will not change the status of the `openFile`.

Comment: Look inside of the `while` loop and convince yourself that the fragments `cin >>` and `cout <<` make sense. If you don't understand what `cin >>` and `cout <<` mean - ask.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You are neither reading nor writing to `openFile`.
You need to use `operator<<` or `operator>>` with openFile.